# Wildcard Subdomains with CakePHP htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I currently have this CakePHP Setup: [Variable Prefixed Routing in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463716/variable-prefixed-routing-in-cakephp)

DNS for `*.example.com` and Apache Entries for handling Wildcard subdomains is already present. Unfortunately, I can't seem to be able to merge the CakePHP's default .htaccess with wildcard subdomain code.

The following is the CakePHP default .htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Example of what I'd like to do:
`example.com/controller/action/a` -> `example.com/global/controller/action/a` (`global` is literal)

`X.example.com/controller/action/a/b/c` -> `example.com/X/controller/action/a/b/c`
Essentially make the X to be the first "directory", then maintain the rest of the URL.
(`X` is any alphanumeric string)

Note that folder `X` definitely doesn't exist, it is simply rewritten to CakePHP to `app/webroot` once accessed. I don't want to modify the CakePHP part's behavior, I just need the URL examples above to be rewritten to the "equivalent" of accessing that page, then it'll be handled by CakePHP's `htaccess` entries.

For reference, `app/webroot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? (would go above the app/webroot rules you have above):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^controller/(.*)$ /%1/controller/$1 [L]
```

This should get applied first, then the app/webroot rules should take effect and point it to: `/app/webroot/%1/controller/$1`.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't write my question properly - I'd like everything after X.example.com to go to example.com/X/(other things here).