# CakePHP Routing MissingControllerException

Tags: cakephp, routes

I currently have a CakePHP route setup from: [Variable Prefixed Routing in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463716/variable-prefixed-routing-in-cakephp)

Here's my routes.php:

```
Router::connect(
    "/:forum/:controller/:action/*",
    array(),
    array("pass" => array("forum"))
);

Router::connect(
    "/:forum",
    array(
        "controller" => "forums",
        "action" => "index"
    ),
    array("pass" => array("forum"))
);
```

This works perfectly, for example `/example/users/login` will be routed to UsersController::login, and `$this->request->params["forum"]` will contain `example`.

However, upon looking at `tmp/logs/debug.log` I see that there are a lot of errors produced by this route, and I can't understand why this happens because the routing apparently works perfectly:

```
2012-08-22 02:29:09 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class ExampleController could not be found.
#0 /var/www/app/webroot/index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
```

It essentially is attempting to look for a ExampleController (because I am trying to access `/example/users/login`), but `routes.php` specifically tells CakePHP to look for Users controller as opposed to Example Controller.

Is there a way to fix this issue? I cannot understand why it happens since everything *apparently* works correctly.

Comment: Try to combined both of routing statements into one and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does /example/users work, as in does it route to UsersController::index(). If not, you should need a route for just /:forum/:controller so try adding this before your current routes and see if it clears up the errors:

```
Router::connect(
    "/:forum/:controller",
    array('action' => 'index'),
    array("pass" => array("forum"))
);
```

Comment: No, `/example/users` doesn't work - I've added that route and I'll see if this issue can be reproduced again. (It only happens on my production server, localhost reports nothing even when debug = 0) For now, this is accepted - thanks a lot!